# Analogue of function convert2sur from Matlab in R

Tags: r, matlab, regression

I need to use in my code in R analogue of function convert2sur from Matlab (see here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/convert2sur.html.
Is there some analogue of this in R, or how to write it manually?

Comment: Package `systemfit` has SUR estimation. Available on CRAN. I wouldn't know where to find conversion or how you could convert.

Comment: Thanks! The task was to convert Matlab code into R, so at first I thought that there are must be exact analogues.